# Get Clob From Oracle 10g Causing High CPU Usage

Tags: performance, oracle, spring, jdbc, clob

I am trying to read data from Oracle 10g in my Java program and one of the column is CLOB type as follow (Note: data is the column of CLOB type):

```
private final static String LOAD_QUERY 
        = "SELECT id, data FROM table WHERE id = ?";

    public SomeObject loadById(long id){
        SomeObject obj = null;
        try {
            obj = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(LOAD_QUERY,
                    new ParameterizedRowMapper<SomeObject>() {
                public Model mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    long id = rs.getLong("id");
                    String data = rs.getString("data");
                    return new SomeObject(id, data);
                }
            }, id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SomeException("Error during SQL query", ErrorCode.INTERNAL_ERROR, e);
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

The data size being stored in CLOB is as big as 44Mb. I am able to retrieve the CLOB value successfully but it is a big hit on cpu usage. After running profiler with Java VisualVM, it seems like it is an IO problem. How should i go about resolving this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you define "big hit"?  Are you talking milliseconds?  Seconds?  Minutes?  You say it is generating a lot of CPU usage.  Is that on the database server?  Or on the application server?  And then you say that it seems like an I/O problem.  How do you get from a CPU problem to an I/O problem?  If it was an I/O problem, you'd expect that you'd see a lot of I/O waits when you profiled the code not a lot of CPU waits.

Comment: It takes a couple of seconds when it reads the CLOB data. And there is a spike in CPU usage to about 50% during the read. When I inspect it with a java profiler, most of the cpu time is spent at the java.net.SocketInputStream.read().

Comment: I'm guessing that the CPU spike you're talking about is on the application server, correct? If you are pushing 44 MB of data over the network from the database server to the application server, a couple of seconds seems pretty reasonable.  It would take a little more than 4 seconds to transfer that much data over a 100baseT ethernet network assuming there is no other traffic on the network. So the fact that you're using half of a CPU to keep up with the network card seems pretty reasonable to me.  Is there a reason that you would expect to be able to transfer the data faster?

Comment: yes, i am seeing the cpu spike on the application server. it takes around 4.7 seconds to transfer 44MB data from database server to application server. this application server is being occupied by bunch of other services too. so i am thinking if i can transfer data faster, i can spare more cpu time for other services. this would be a problem if this application transferring big amount of data frequently and occupying cpu time frequently. thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Do you believe that the network connection between the servers is able to transfer the data more quickly than what you are seeing?  As I said previously, it would take a bit more than 4 seconds to transfer that much data if you are saturating a 100baesT network.  Does your network have more throughput than that?

Answer (score 0):

If its a large clob, I recommend trying to retrieve the contents via a stream.
By using getString, a large array would be allocated, the might also be a large array allocated by the 2nd level cache, there could even be multiple arrays allocated while the value is value copied through different layers of the underlying framework.
All this string allocation and copying would cause a high CPU usage.

Comment: I have tried using an InputStream and retrieve CLOB data as byte array and do the conversion to String in my program. However, the bottle neck happens at java.net.SocketInputStream.read() when I inspect it with a java profiler.

Comment: That means its waiting for the data to come from the database.  If the data is streamed slowly, it still uses as much cpu as if it comes quickly.  Need to look at optimising the stream/clob on the db side.  Perhaps you could gzip the contents of the clob field.

Comment: yes, i have tried to compress with gzip and utilized mime encoding before storing the huge data into database. from my experiment, it does shows that the smaller amount of data being transferred, the less cpu time is being consumed. from your experience, what is the performance difference if i am reading big data from blob versue clob type column?

Comment: I dont know about blob vs clob performance wise, should not be much difference I would think.  Mime encoding will make the content larger no?  When streaming data, you want to make sure all the processing happens in stream, rather than streaming all the content and then processing it.  Are you using the GZIPInputStream?